# How to find the difference between two hours in java

Tags: java, time

Im trying to find the difference between two given hours. Such as if it were 1 pm and 10 pm the difference would b 9. I can already do this if it were in the same afternoon or both times in the morning. But What I cant figure out how do do is find the difference between two numbers in the seperate AM and PM. I fooled around and came up with this.

```
if(AmPm1.equalsIgnoreCase("PM")){
        time1+=12;
    }
    if(AmPm2.equalsIgnoreCase("PM")){
        time2+=12;
    }
```

I works for numbers like 9 AM and 1 pm by adding 12 to the 9 to make it on a 24hr clock and then just subtract them. But what I cant do its with something like 10pm and 2 am. The difference is 4 but if I try my method the difference is much higher. All replies will help.

Comment: use `java.util.Date` to get difference in time.

Comment: You are getting only hours as input ? like `9AM` ?

Comment: Yes I am forced to used input supplied to me. Its for a lab. So it could be 3pm and 5pm. 2am and 10pm.

Comment: in case of 10pm and 2am how can u get positive dude , show your full code.. according to ur logic u should get 2 - (10 + 12) = -20, so u just have to put an if conditoin : if the diffrence is negative add 24 and then print the answer..

Comment: @AlexMarkovich i hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113557/calculate-the-difference-b-w-two-given-times-in-java) should solve your purpose